# Adding 3 projects to version control (SVN) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, version-control

I'm currently developing an application, and I have worked in the last weeks with the following 3-project setup :

- the code itself;
- unit tests;
- acceptance tests.

Until now, I had only the `code itself` under version control. I'm researching on how to include all the 3 projects under version control. I'd like to have everything under the same repository. I've created 3 folders(one for each project) under my SVN repo.

In a new workspace, I've imported each one of the projects into Eclipse. This seems, at first, to be working fine, but I'm not sure if I won't get problems later on when trying to make commits to the server and the different projects aren't in the most recent update.

I'd guess this wouldn't be a problem as they don't share any file, at all, but I'm not really sure. Is this the correct approach for the given situation? How would you handle this?

Comment: Why have 3 separate projects? The tests are essential to the code they are testing. I would put all this stuff in the same project.

Comment: @AndrewFielden - sometimes it can be better to separate the tests into a different project as they may require a different Java Build Path (due to JUnit)

Comment: @Andrew: dependencies and I need full rebuilds before each test run, for several reasons. I wouldn't want to do that with the main code.

Comment: Try to use Ant or Maven instead of Eclipse embedded building functionality. It will allow separating tests compilation phase, project compilation phase and compilation/building of whatever else.

Answer (score 1):

You create a local project in Eclipse, right-click on it, and select Team/Share project...

Then a wizard will guide you, and allow putting the code into the correct folder of the svn server.